# CMake $<TARGET_FILE:tgt> generator expression along with DeployQt5

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to deploy my Qt-based app under CMake. I used to use DeployQt5 in that way:

```
if (APPLE)
  set (QT_QPA_PLUGIN ${QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS}/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib)
  set (tgt_EXECUTABLE tgt.app)
elseif (WIN32 AND MSVC)
  set (QT_QPA_PLUGIN ${QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS}/platforms/qwindows.dll)
  get_property (tgt_EXECUTABLE TARGET tgt PROPERTY LOCATION)
  get_filename_component (tgt_EXECUTABLE ${tgt_EXECUTABLE} NAME)
endif ()

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_DESTINATION ".")
include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)

include (DeployQt5)
install_qt5_executable ("${tgt_EXECUTABLE}"
"${QT_QPA_PLUGIN}" # qtplugins
"" # libs
"${QT_INSTALL_LIBS}" # dirs
```

)

but I don't like it. I want to use cmake's generator expressions and abandon the LOCATION property. I wonder if it is possible with the DeployQt5 module. It does not seem to be that straightforward:

```
include (DeployQt5)
install_qt5_executable ("$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>"
    "${QT_QPA_PLUGIN}" # qtplugins
    "" # libs
    "${QT_INSTALL_LIBS}" # dirs
)
```

doesn't work. Is it possible to make that part of the CMakeLists.txt file cleaner?